# MongoDB - How do I retrieve multiple data and express as array of values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a db with 3 collections:

1. events
2. customers
3. ratings

I want to retrieve all the events, all the customers, and each of the customer ratings of each event. And then represent the data as an array of values.

[image: how I want the data to be represented, as well as the schema and relationship of the 3 collections]

- The ratings schema also contains a **value** attribute.
- rating 1, rating 2 ... represent the rating of event 1, event 2 ...
- User 1, User 2 ... represent the customers
- The different arrays represent the users, and each value in the that array represents their rating of an event.

I am doing this on **node.js** and **mongoose**

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried

Comment: haven't tried anything. don't know where to start

Comment: Are you trying to create the final result set using Mongo only? If not, depending on the size of the DB, you could retrieve the events, ratings and customers, then using 'for' loops to generate your matrix using Node.

Comment: You need Mongoose's [population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). It's pretty much the equivalent of SQL's `JOIN`.